# Android centered box

Tags: android, view, center

I have this custom view that should display a centered box in the page, with different resolutions and displays.

(i removed all the code relative to the text, etc):

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(context, attrs);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


        Paint x = new Paint();
        x.setColor(Color.BLUE);


        Resources r = getResources();               

        //dimension of display
         int displayW = r.getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
         int displayH = r.getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

         //
         int boxW = 200;
         int boxH = 300;

         //actual box dimensions
         float boxEffettivaW = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, boxW, r.getDisplayMetrics());
         float boxEffettivaH = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, boxH, r.getDisplayMetrics());



         float left = (displayW-boxEffettivaW) / 2;
         float top = (displayH-boxEffettivaH) / 2;
         float right = left + boxEffettivaW;
         float bottom = top + boxEffettivaH;


        RectF boxf = new RectF();
        boxf.set(left,top,right,bottom);    
        canvas.drawRect(boxf, x);       



    }

}
```

My issue is that the box is not centered, because of the android application title bar, and because of the notify bar. [screenshot](http://s9.postimage.org/ref85f6zx/screenshots.png)

So, how can i center my box?
I'd need to know the size of the actual app-dedicated display area, not the global display size...

Comment: i later recall the CustomView inside the xml. the box has inside some text and image and other stuff, so i preferred to have a single View (CustomView) where putting all my elements into

Comment: declare your view in xml inside a RelativeLayout that cover all the screen ( width and height to `match_parent` ) , and use the attribut : `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

Comment: @Houcine and what value should i give to the android:layout_height and android:layout_width of my customview in the xml?

Comment: give them what you want in dp , or just use wrap_content. whatever the width or the height it is , the view will be exactly centered in the parent layout